# use crunch to generate all the possible IATA codes comsbination

Tags: crunch

I don't really know how to formulate this, but I have a bunch of IATA codes, and I want to generate all the possible combinations ex : JFK/LAX, BOS/JFK, ...etc, separated by a character such as "/" or "|".

Comment: When is a combination "possible"? Without restrictions there are infinitely many combinations. To make this finite, a restriction could be "inside one combination the same code may appear at most once" or "a combination contains at most X codes".

Comment: 2 by 2, for example for JFK make : JFK/LAS, JFK/DEN, JFK/BOS, ...etc, for all the other IATA codes, and once we're done with JFK, the same for BOS : BOS/JFK, BOS/DEN, ...etc

Comment: I don't want it to make combinations with a IATA code as such JFK, KFJ, JKF, KFJ, ...etc.
idk if "combinations" is the right word

Comment: "Combination" is correct, but very broad. In your case "pair" (without `X/X`) would have been clearer :)

Answer (score 1):

Here we assume your IATA codes are stored in the file `file`; one code per line.

`crunch` has the `-q` option which generates permutations of lines from a file. However, in this mode `crunch` ignores most of the other options like `<max-len>`, which would be important here to print only pairs of codes.

Therefore, it would be easier and faster to …

#### Use something different than `crunch`

For instance, try

```
join -j2 -t/ -o 1.1 2.1 file file | awk -F/ '$1!=$2'
```

If you really, really, really want, you can …

#### Translate the input into something `crunch` can work with

We translate each line from `file` to a unique single character, supply that list of characters to `crunch`, and then translate the result back.

`crunch` supports Unicode characters, so files with more than 255 lines are totally fine. Here we enumerate the lines in `file` by characters in Unicode's [Supplementary Private Use Area-A](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/plane/U+F0000). Therefore, `file` may have at most 65'534 lines.
If you need more lines, you could combine multiple Unicode planes, but at some point you might run into `ARG_MAX` issues. Also, with 65'534 lines you would already generate (a bit less than) 65'534^2 = 4'294'705'156 pairs, occupying more than 34 GB when translated into pairs of IATA codes.

I suspect the back-translation to be a huge slowdown, so above alternative seems to be better in every aspect (efficiency, brevity, maintainability, …).

```
# This assumes your locale is using any Unicode encoding,
# e.g. UTF-8, UTF-16, … (doesn't matter which one).

file=...
((offset=0xF0000))
charset=$(
  echo -en "$(bc <<< "obase=16;
    max=$offset+$(wc -l < "$file");
    for(i=$offset;i<max;i++) {\"\U\"; i}" |
    tr -d \\n
  )"
)
crunch 2 2 "$charset" -d 1@ --stdout |
iconv -t UTF-32 |
od -j4 -tu4 -An -w12 -v |
awk -v o="$offset" 'NR==FNR{a[o+NR-1]=$0;next} {print a[$1]"/"a[$2]}' "$file" -
```

Comment: I..I seriously think your answer is above my level of understanding of crunch-wordlist, it would take me longer to make sens of what you said than to type every possible combination by hand

Comment: **tl;dr:** `crunch` cannot generate pairs of words, but it can generate pairs of characters. For the words `JFK LAX BOS` use `crunch 2 2 abc -d 1@` to generate `ab ac ba bc ca cb` and then replace `a`→`JFK` and `b`→`LAX` and `c`→`BOS` to get a pairs of words.

Comment: But as I said: It is easier to drop `crunch` entirely and use `join -j2 -t/ -o 1.1 2.1 file file | awk -F/ '$1!=$2'` instead. Do you need any help with that command too?

Comment: YEEEEEEES, thank you, exactly what I was looking for, thanks mate

Comment: @Ash Glad to hear this solved your problem. Please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) this answer to close the question.